# Rendering VueJS prop within HTML array

Tags: html, vue.js

I have an HTML array with data like so:

```
data-groups='["category_all", "data goes here"]'
```

I have a prop called "title" which contains the string I need to render in the "data goes here" area. I've tried using v-bind, but then I lose the array which I need to have in order for the original sort feature to work.

I google'd a few different ways to either escape or render quotes, and most refer to v-bind which again, won't work in this instance.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Just a thought. Can you create a computed property like- `computed: {dataGroups() {return ['category_all', this.prop_title]}}` and use it in data-groups like- `:data-groups="dataGroups"`. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "I've tried using v-bind, but then I lose the array". Array binding works well with Vue

Answer (score 2):

I was using Shuffle.js and for anyone else seeking an answer, it was in the documentation:

https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/docs/getting-started

> Alternatively, you can set the delimiter option to a comma (delimiter: ',') and the data-groups attribute will be split on that character.

Then changing the above line of code to:

```
:data-groups="item.category.title + ',all'"
```

works just fine :)